# Can airlines refuse to board me if there is not much time left on my student visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, france, long-stay-visas

I'm an Indian citizen and I have a student visa valid for France. I came back to India in April because I didn't like my school there and decided to pursue a language course instead of my actual studies. I talked with my prefecture in the area and the immigration department told me that I have full right to pursue a different course. So I'm good on that side. I have two questions.

1.) Since I'd be leaving from India and will have only 2.5 months left in my student visa, will need to buy a return ticket, despite having a Long-Stay D visa? I'm asking this because some friend of mine told me that if I have less time left in my student visa, airline may ask for a return ticket. Also, I might extend my visas once I'm in France so that's another reason why I wouldn't be comfortable in purchasing a return ticket.

2.) Will the airlines refuse to board me just for the sole reason that I don't have enough time left in my student visa?

Comment: any update on this